# Alt gr + number changes voice type and does not give me key

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, narrator, ease-of-access

When I type alt gr + a number it says on the screen for example "Voice type: Robotic Voice" and it does not give me the key I want. How do I disable this so I can type curly brackets and stuff again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When I type alt gr + a number it says on the screen eg "Voice type: Robotic Voice"

This appears to be caused by [Clownfish for Skype](https://clownfish-translator.com/index.html).

From their [FAQ](https://clownfish-translator.com/faq.html):

> Q: My keyboard does not work as expected. Some keys don't work any
>   more ( AltGr+2, '@' sign, etc. ) What should I do?
>
> A: Clownfish can be controlled by hotkeys ( keyboard shortcuts ). In
>   some configurations these hotkeys affect system behavior. To solve the
>   problem you have to change Clownfish's hotkey combination or just
>   disable them( Menu->Preferences->Hotkeys). Sorry about your troubles.

---

#### No @-sign on my keyboard! Clownfish is the answer...

> When pressing Alt Gr + 1, +2, +3 ... all numbers as follow: (The short description show on the screen at the position of the mouse)

```
Alt Gr + 1: "Voice type: Alien (useless)"
Alt Gr + 2: "Voice type: Atari Game"
Alt Gr + 3: "Voice type: Clone"
Alt Gr + 4: "Voice type: Mutation (slow)"
Alt Gr + 5: "Voice type: Mutation"
Alt Gr + 6: "Voice type: Mutation (fast)"
Alt Gr + 7: "Voice type: Robotic Voice"
Alt Gr + 8: "Voice type: Pitch (male)"
Alt Gr + 9: "Voice type: Pitch (female)"
Alt Gr + 0: "Voice type: disabled"
```

...

> If you have "clownfish" for skype or other...is this aplication. Because I delete this program and this problem solved

...

> Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> I hate this software! The user interface is so poor and the whole
>   program is all confusing, annoying and extremely provocative
>   inefficient.
>
> Now, also with the at-sign...! Phew!

Source [No @-sign on my keyboard! Clownfish is the answer...](https://forum.xojo.com/17941-no-sign-on-my-keyboard-clownfish-is-the-answer/7)